# Create custom finder with spring repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo with repository layers. I have two classes: Document (with the title of the document) and FilledDocument (that contains the related Document). Like this:

```
public class Document {

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    private String titleDocument;
    ...
}

public class FilledDocument {

    /**
     */
    @OneToOne
    private Document relatedDocument;
    ...
}
```

I would want to create a finder for the class FilledDocument that match for title inside of the atribute relatedDocument.

I am using a solution that isnt elegant and efficient. In my controller I have:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "find", produces = "text/html")
public String findFilledDocumentsByTitleDocumentContaining(@RequestParam(value = "title", required = true) String title, Model uiModel) {

    LinkedList<FilledDocument> allFilledDocuments = new LinkedList<FilledDocument>();
    allFilledDocuments.addAll(filledDocumentService.findAllFilledDocuments());

    ArrayList<FilledDocument> filledDocuments=new ArrayList<FilledDocument>();

    for( FilledDocument filledDocument : allFilledDocuments ) {
        if( filledDocument.getRelatedDocument().getTitleDocument().toLowerCase().contains(title.toLowerCase()) == true ) {
            filledDocuments.add(filledDocument);
        }
    }       

    uiModel.addAttribute("filleddocuments", filledDocuments);
    return "filleddocuments/list";
}
```

I am reading this [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query) and I am trying with @Query in the repository class, like this:

```
@Query("select f from FilledDocument f where f.relatedDocument.titleDocument containing = ?1")
public ArrayList<FilledDocument> findFilledDocumentByTitleDocument(@Param("titleDocument") String titleDocument);
```

but it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring Data JPA 1.3.1 or newer that you can just write :

```
@Query("select f from FilledDocument f where f.relatedDocument.titleDocument like %:title%")
List<FilledDocument> findFilledDocumentByTitleDocument(@Param("title") String titleDocument);
```

If you are stuck on an older version then your code would be:

```
@Query("select f from FilledDocument f where f.relatedDocument.titleDocument like :title")
List<FilledDocument> findFilledDocumentByTitleDocument(@Param("title") String titleDocument);
```

And when you call the `findFilledDocumentByTitleDocument` method you need to pass

`"%"+title+"%"`

as an argument.

Check out [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-new-like-expressions-of-spring-data-jpa/) blog post for the full story and section `1.3.4` of the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

Comment: I am using spring-data-jpa 1.4.3.RELEASE. If I add this to the repository class now my app doesnt pass the test. I am using Spring Roo 1.2.5

Comment: I get no error. The test phase is (I think) in a infinity loop. I was waiting 15 minutes and no output (normaly it takes 1 minute)

Comment: @PedroGonzalez Glad you got it sorted out!